# Add ip route when connecting to specific WiFi

Tags: networking, systemd

Is it possible to automatically set a route if I connect to a specific WiFi?

A WiFi, I regularly use, hosts their login page on 172.20.5.22, which is not in the same network as the ip I get for my WiFi. Unfortunately some docker network also uses the 172.20.0.0/16 network. So after connecting I add the static route:

```
ip route add 172.20.5.22/32 via 192.168.16.1
```

Is there a way to automate this? Maybe with systemd?

I use GNOME 3.28.1 as Desktop

Comment: Have you reviewed related docs in `man networkd.conf` and `man systemd.network`?

Comment: Instead of messing with static routes, consider reconfiguring Docker so it doesn't use the 172.20.0.0/16 network anymore. See for instance [this documentation on how to customize the `docker0` bridge](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/). Hopefully this would also solve your issue!